# Build complex query in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I want to build query after in laravel 5

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE updated_at IN (
   SELECT max(updated_at) FROM tbl
   WHERE created_at BETWEEN $begin_time AND $end_time 
   GROUP BY ip_address)
```

My code:

```
$sqlStr = self::select('*')
        ->whereIn('updated_at', function($query){
                         return $query->select(self::raw('max(updated_at)'))
                             ->whereRaw('created_at >= $begin_time)
                             ->whereRaw('created_at <= $end_time)
                             ->groupBy('ip_address');
})->toSql();
var_dump(($sqlStr));die;
```

Error information:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
>   strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Please help me.

Comment: Are your $begin_time and $end_time strings or Carbon date? Also you should use bind parameters and not concatenating strings to insert variables, this way you will be more secure and you will avoid the problem you might have here with missing ' in the whereRaw statements

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote `self::raw('max(updated_at)')` that generates `SELECT max(updated_at) FROM tbl` which is already inside a select command. Following code will work:

```
$sqlStr = self::select('*')
    ->whereIn('updated_at', function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('max(updated_at)')
            ->from('tbl')
            ->whereRaw('created_at >= $begin_time')
            ->whereRaw('created_at <= $end_time')
            ->groupBy('ip_address');
})->toSql();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this should work too:

```
DB::select(
    'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE updated_at IN (' .
        'SELECT max(updated_at) FROM tbl ' .
        'WHERE created_at BETWEEN :begin_time AND :end_time ' .
        'GROUP BY ip_address '
    ')',
    [
        'begin_time' => $begin_time,
        'end_time' => $end_time
    ]
);
```